Implement of triggers postgresql to cockroachdb
I'm trying to migrate a database written in PostgreSQL to cockroachDB I want to know if there's a way to implement the trigger in SQL in cockroachDB. I know cocroachDB not supported triggers but I want to implements trigger functions to cockroachdb diffrent way or solutions.
In postgresql example triggers I wrote here
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."distance"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
previous_odometer numeric;
  calculated_distance numeric;
BEGIN
  -- Get the most recent odometer_midnight for the same vehicle prior to the current download_date
SELECT odometer_midnight INTO previous_odometer
FROM vu_daily_data_activities
WHERE vehicle_id = NEW.vehicle_id
  AND download_date < NEW.download_date
ORDER BY download_date DESC
    LIMIT 1;

-- Calculate the day_distance
IF previous_odometer IS NOT NULL THEN
    calculated_distance := NEW.odometer_midnight - previous_odometer;
    IF calculated_distance < 0 THEN
      NEW.day_distance := 0;  -- Set to 0 if calculated distance is negative
ELSE
      NEW.day_distance := calculated_distance;
END IF;
ELSE
    NEW.day_distance := 0;  -- If no previous record, set day_distance to 0
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100


See the manual: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/plpgsql

CockroachDB, unlike traditional relational databases like PostgreSQL or MySQL, does not natively support database triggers. However, you can mimic the behavior of triggers in CockroachDB by implementing CDC, Kafka and write a custom function which updates tables according to your needs.

Steps to be taken:

Enable CDC on the table using CREATE CHANGEFEED FOR TABLE ... 
Set Up Kafka and Create a Topic
Set Up a Kafka Consumer to Process Changes (in python, .net, java or any other language you prefer)

